Microsoft's newer (templated) CString does not handle null characters the way it did before
// this is the old MFC CString (not actually dependant on CObject) vs the new ATL version that is implemented as a template
char array[] = { 0x45, 0x46, 0x0, 0x45 };

CString a(array,sizeof array);
CString b;
int _aLen = a.GetLength();
// in vc6 _aLen is 4 
// in vs2019 _aLen is 4

b += a;

int _bLen = b.GetLength();
// in vc6 _bLen is 4 
// in vs2019 _bLen is 2! `


I can see why it is doing this. But.... Since we can give CString (one of its constructors) a pointer and a length and that actually works, why would an operator such as += or even the CString Append() function not use the length of the source string when it concatenates the string? This makes it extremely difficult to upgrade old projects to newer (visual studio) compilers. Is there a build/compile option I am missing here?
I tried changing unicode to MBCS with no difference.  I also tried to step into the source but was unable to do that because I could not seem to get the source files to match the build.  I was able to step into the disassembly and right up until the actual concatenation the string that was passed to operator += had length 4 but coming out the destination string only had length 2.

sizeof array is not valid C++

@PepijnKramer why do you say that?

Under the Remarks section of the concatenation operator there is a note: "Although it is possible to create CStringT instances that contain embedded null characters, we recommend against it. Calling methods and operators on CStringT objects that contain embedded null characters can produce unintended results."

If you're talking about the brackets, @PepijnKramer , you don't need them. But there are some cases where they really, really help.

@user4581301 I've never used it without them (I must have missed that somehow in the last 30 years or so). Anyway using std::string_view should be an option too ;)

@PepijnKramer sizeof used with a type requires parenthesis, used with a variable or expression does not (unless operator precedence kicks in the wrong way). Personally, I always use parenthesis and don't worry about which is which.

@AviBerger Could well be I made that choice ages ago... never looked back ;)

@BobC Well, it seems you're out of luck.  The source code to the CStringT::operator= calls CString::Append, and Append does this: nLength = StringLengthN(pszSrc, nLength);.  The comment in the source code explicitly states that only up to the terminating null will be considered.  But I have to say this -- upgrading from VC6, a version that is a quarter-century years old, to the latest version of Visual Studio -- somewhere along the line you were bound to get incompatibility issues somewhere.

This makes it extremely difficult to upgrade old projects to newer (visual studio) compilers. -- You have VC 7, VC 2002, VC 2003, VC 2005, VC 2008, VC 2013, VC 2015, VC 2017, VC 2019, VC 2022,  and I may have missed a few of them.  That's at least 10 compiler versions away from VC 6, which wasn't even a standard's conforming compiler.  So would it be fair for Microsoft to make sure their latest compiler supports VC 6?  Even going from VC 6 to VC 7 had issues (I know of one, where no code that assumed that vector iterators were pointers would compile successfully in VC 7).
